# Which figure of speech is this?

Tags: figures-of-speech

Suppose I've written a story that is set in ancient times. And I refer to something quite modern in it. Like I'm writing about the roman empire suppose, and I write 'He looked at the time in his watch...'. We know they didn't have watches at that time. So is this called something? I remember a teacher telling me that many authors used this and it was called something, but I don't remember what. I think even Shakespeare used it somewhere...

Comment: Shakespeare certainly did it—whether intentionally or not, I can't say. The example I remember from high school is the exchange between Banquo and Fleance at Inverness Castle: Banquo: _How goes the night, boy?_ Fleance: _The moon is down; I have not heard the clock._ According the textbook I was reading, there were no clocks to hear in Inverness Castle—or anywhere else in that part of the world—during Duncan's reign as King of Scotland (1034–1040). So Fleance's reference to a clock (chronometer though it be) that he has not heard is anachronistic.

Comment: @SvenYargs: and yet, _not hearing_ it does not make his statement false, as _hearing the clock_ certainly would have ;)

Comment: What you are describing is not a **figure of speech**. It is a literary device, when done deliberately, but says absolutely nothing about the way in which you use the language to describe the anachronism.

Answer (score 5):

That sounds like an **anachronism**. Here's a [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anachronism) about it.

[Merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anachronism)  says this about it:

> something (such as a word, an object, or an event) that is mistakenly placed in a time where it does not belong in a story, movie, etc.

Comment: The other important instance from Shakespeare is when the clock strikes in *Julius Caesar*.

Comment: @WS2: But that clock must have been brought by the unicorns! (The ones that were betrayed by trees.)

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about the clock example.